# How to wait for a button to be clicked?

Tags: c#, .net

After a button is clicked in a Windows form application written in C#, how to wait for another button to be clicked? Meanwhile I am updating a datagridview dynamically by current information.

**EDIT**

After button1 is clicked, I want to repeatedly update a dataGridView with current information and when button2 is clicked I want to stop updating the dataGridView.

Comment: It is not clear, what you mean by *wait for another button to be clicked*...Do you mean to disable all user input on the form except that button? Or what?

Comment: You attach a listener to the event pump and then handle the click event when it occurs.

Comment: As simple as it says. Suppose button1 is clicked, i want the program to wait for another button to be clicked. Once button1 is clicked I want to update the dataGridView dynamically. It's keep updating until button2 is pressed.

Comment: If it were as simple as it says, people would not be asking you for clarity... Buttons have click event handler which are executed only when they are clicked. So in effect the program is "waiting for the button to be clicked."

Comment: I didn't get you. I want to stop updating the dataGridView. I am updating that in a method. I want to call the method repeatedly whenever button1 has been pressed until the button2 is pressed.
Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually when you are IN your problem, you forgot others' view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create it
        timer = new Timer(); 
        // set the interval, so it'll fire every 1 sec. (1000 ms)
        timer.Interval = 1000; 
        // bind an event handler
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 

        //...
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do what you need
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start(); //start the timer
        // switch buttons
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;        
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop(); //stop the timer
        // switch buttons back
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

From MSDN:

> A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This
>   Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI
>   threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code
>   have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same
>   thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.
>
> When you use this timer, use the Tick event to perform a polling
>   operation or to display a splash screen for a specified period of
>   time. Whenever the Enabled property is set to true and the Interval
>   property is greater than zero, the Tick event is raised at intervals
>   based on the Interval property setting.

Comment: Served my purpose. Thank you very much. And again sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @soham.m17 you are always welcome...`inconvenience` is when the OP doen't wish to respond to the comments...here it's OK

Answer (score 0):

So you have button A and button B.  When button A is pressed you want to wait for button B to be pressed, then do something special?  Without more information the simplest way is something like this:

```
private void OnButtonAClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonA.Enabled = false;
    ButtonA.Click -= OnButtonAClicked;
    ButtonB.Click += OnButtonBClicked;
    ButtonB.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnButtonBClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonB.Enabled = false;
    ButtonB.Click -= OnButtonBClicked;

    // Do something truly special here

    ButtonA.Click += OnButtonAClicked;
    ButtonA.Enabled = true;
}
```

This code will toggle(initial state; button A is enabled, button B is disabled), when button A is pressed, button B   becomes enabled and processes events, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BackgroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

It doesn't freeze the UI, support ProgressBar, also it can be async. At the link you will see a good example with same functional that you want (start some task by click on one button and cancel it by click on another button).